# Passing plumbing through a wall.

Tags: plumbing

I'm installing a dishwasher from scratch. The only place to put it is in the breakfast nook off the kitchen. I've already successfully installed the electric. Next, I need to install the drain and water feed line.

[image]

I would like to pass the plumbing where the red x is. The plumbing will be a braided stainless steel water line and a flexible drain line. I would also like for the lines to be serviceable after the fact.

My best idea is to embed a 1.5in or 2in pvc pipe in the wall. Glue the pipe to the lath in the wall and then fill the gaps with joint compound.

Is this a good idea or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you implying that you have plaster and lath? The home looks more modern than that. Regardless, I'd just use a desktop grommet.

Comment: @isherwood The house is 1930 and has horsehair plaster and lath. What is a desktop grommet?

Comment: Are you trying to run a riser or flexline through the wall to the dishwasher? Why not run PEX through your cabinetry and connect it to the water supply for your sink (assuming it's nearby). I suppose I'm still a little unclear on what you're trying to do, and what the issue is.

Comment: @HariGanti Yes, I'm running a flex line to the dishwasher and a flexible drain from the dishwasher to the garbage disposal.

Comment: @vini_i Are you routing all of this through the cabinetry in the picture? Are you routing it through the wall? Can you ensure a proper air-gap or downslope for the drain over that distance? There's a proper way to do this, and this isn't it (unless you're just going into the adjacent cabinet).

Comment: The better way: Remove either base cabinet from the left or right of the sink; which look like 36"ers, so you'll need like a 8~12" new base cab to fill the gap, which is prob upwards of $400, so consider using just an end panel.

Comment: maybe open up the floor of the cabinets and run the lines through the baseboard and under the cabinets.

Comment: @HariGanti The garbage disposal is located in the fourth cabinet from the left. The inlet to the garbage disposal is located below the opening of the door. This gives it about a 4in drop over about a 5foot span. What air gap are you referring to and how would I maintain it?

Comment: @vini_i Air gaps may be required in your jurisdiction. You should check. http://www.sfgate.com/homeandgarden/sweatequity/article/Ways-to-hook-up-a-dishwasher-2561066.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dishwashers don't require a full size drain. There is no need to run a DWV line to your dishwasher.

They drain through a 5/8" or 7/8" flexible hose that attaches to the sink tail piece or the food disposal unit.

They fill through a 1/2" feed line.

You shouldn't need larger than a 1 ½" hole through the wall into your cabinetry and then run the lines in the back of your cabinets. I think you will want to go lower though since your drawers probably go all the way to the back of the cabinets and anything mounted there would keep them from closing.

Have you bought the DW unit? If you have it, check the install instructions and the feed and drain line sizes.